# How stable are the unofficial builds of Blender?

Tags: versions

I'd like to try to use the Bevel shader, but unfortunately it's only available in the daily build of Blender 2.79. I was wondering, just how stable is that build? Is it good enough for everyday work, or only for testing?

Comment: Yes that should be stable, Just don't use 2.8 for work yet.

Comment: Unofficial releases, daily and experimental builds are to be used at your own risk. The best way to find out is by trying it.  But if you are working on something you would regret loosing, then stick to the official releases.

Comment: We get daily builds of v2.79. That's ok. There is an official statement to not to use this builds for important projects.

But will this daylies sometime be released officially before v2.8?

There are a lot of important bug fixes in the daylies especially in cycles renderer.